# How to copy text from Nox emulator on MacOS?

Tags: macos, android-emulator

A colleague of mine has `MacOS` laptop and works with `apk` on `Nox` Android emulator.

There is a usual `EditText` field with a text. If we `copy` text (after long tap) from the `EditText`, it will appear in the Clipboard, but only inside `Nox` emulator. We can use the text in Chrome browser, for instance. Command + C doesn't work, while Command + V works (pastes text).

Then we want to paste the text into another application on Mac (TextEdit, Sublime Text, etc.). But it doesn't appear in Mac Clipboard. If I do the same on Windows, it will work right. The only option we found is pasting the text in Chrome browser on any paste-site.

Comment: Yes, we added Google account and sent via documents in Chrome.

Comment: It would be better to use BlueStacks instead of Nox, because the latter is more buggy (sometimes doesn't receive push notifications) in MacOS.